# Android first ImageView in vertical LinearLayout stretching

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: The current popup]

I'm creating the above popup, the content of which consists of rows of horizontal LinearLayout views within a main vertical LinearLayout. Each horizontal LinearLayout contains one ImageView and one TextView.
I'm creating this within a PopupWindow, and doing so programmatically so that I can change the ImageView source as required.

As you can see the first icon seems to take up a lot of space, despite having the same code generating it as the other icons.

Below is the code:

```
 LinearLayout verticalLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainLayoutParams =
                new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
verticalLayout.setLayoutParams(mainLayoutParams);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams iconParams =
                new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//History row
LinearLayout historyLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
historyLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
historyLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
ImageView historyIcon = new ImageView(context);
historyIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_book_grey);
historyIcon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
historyIcon.setLayoutParams(iconParams);
historyLayout.addView(historyIcon);
TextView historyText = new TextView(context);
historyText.setLayoutParams(textParams);
historyText.setText("History");
historyLayout.addView(historyText);
verticalLayout.addView(historyLayout);

//Exam row...
//... (duplicate of history row)
```

I've tried playing around with the layout parameters, even creating a mock xml layout that displays the content as I'd like, to match the parameters to.
If anyone can give some advice on making that book icon the same size as the others, I'd be grateful.

Comment: you should use a listview and create adapter to populate all those texts and images. No need to create multiple layouts programmatically

Comment: I want to be able to select different images as the icons, which (tell me if I'm wrong) I don't think can be done with a listview. Eventually I want to turn this popup into a popup menu, if that helps to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: you can change images easily at runtime in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Add a scaleType to ImageView of fitCenter

Comment: That didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Write this code under `historyIcon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);`

```
historyIcon.setWidth()`
```

And put width according to your layout.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what exactly you meant for me to put as the argument

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't figure out why the first image was scaling differently to the other images, I did find another solution: Using compound left drawables.

```
        historyText.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        Drawable img = m_context.getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.small_book_grey);
                        img.setBounds(0, 0, img.getIntrinsicWidth() * historyText.getMeasuredHeight() / img.getIntrinsicHeight(), historyText.getMeasuredHeight());
                        historyText.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
                        historyText.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
```

Manually setting the bounds to match the TextView worked. Seems clunky, but it was the only way I could get it to do what I was aiming for.

Comment: this may be due to the large image size of the book.